# Limit text height CSS Responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

It seems I am always at odds with 1024 screen resolution.

Texts don't seem to behave well inside div. You set the height of the div and the text just occupies the height it needs to show the the hole thing.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331046/limit-text-inside-div-using-div-height/5331110#5331110), the overflow, it works, but it's not the most elegant solution. 
Is there a way to shrink the whole page do adapt to different screens? We can see the whole newspaper in a cell phone, it shrinks to the size of the media.

Any idea on how to deal with text, height and responsive css?

**EDIT**
You can see the problem [here](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http://sodabrasil.com/paskin.php&w=1024&h=768&a=1&s=1), scroll down the page, some columns/div with full text, so divs with overflow, etc. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show an example of your problem? Create a fiddle and/or post some code

Comment: please see main question for update.

Comment: It looks like you want to limit the text inside a box based on it's height, is that correct?

Comment: yes, but without cutting the text. So the only solution I could see is to proportionally shrink the whole page just like cell phone does. I can't find any resource for that, I am new the programming and the responsive style is not easy...

Comment: Have you tried viewport units? vs vh vmin mvax?

Comment: I had never heard that before! that seems to be ideal. But only 56% of browswers support that. All modern browsers do... That will solve our problems in a few years. I just created a query only for 1024. but it's not ideal. Your suggestion should be the solution if people could update their browsers...Source:http://caniuse.com/viewport-units